# What happens to the reputation of active users if a private beta was closed?

Tags: discussion, private-beta, closed-sites

What happens to the reputation of users of a private beta when it is closed?
Is it counted anywhere on the SE network?

It seems to me that this may only appear for users who are active in Area 51, is this assumption correct?

Comment: Reputation on any site has no effect on other sites (barring the association bonus), so that should answer your two first questions - it doesn't matter if a site is up or has been closed.

Comment: @Oded WHat about the flair?

Comment: @Oded I think he's asking if it's still accessible in any way.

Comment: @Mithrandir - what about the flair? A closed site doesn't show up in the flair.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - it is not clear to me what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What happens to the reputation of users of a private beta when it is closed?

What does reputation mean on a closed site? I'd expect nothing, as the site is closed down - there are no users, there is no reputation.

> Is it counted anywhere on the SE network?

No. The single possible exception is if that site is what caused the association bonus to apply, AFAIK, the association bonus will still apply even if the originating site is closed down (this would be extremely rare).

> It seems to me that this may only appear for users who are active in Area51, is this assumption correct?

Yes. Area51 will still show the reputation earned on the site before it closed.

---

The combined network flair **does not show reputation from closed sites**. It is combining reputation from all sites where you have over 200 reputation.

Comment: I was wondering why some people on Area 51 have a reputation score which is much higher than the sum of their reputation on other sites on the SE network, and found this a plausible explanation so thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - that has nothing to do with it. The Area 51 reputation is its own reputation system that has nothing do to with other sites (in this way it works like reputation does everywhere else on the network).

Comment: Maybe I need to explain i actually have 480 rep on Area 51 but my reputation score (which is shown on proposals I'm following) there is >7K, I 've seen people who have a reputation score of >18K there but if one sums their network reputation they only have >14 K so the only plausible explanation for this difference is their ~4K reputation on a closed/deleted beta site.

Comment: I don't follow. Your reputation on Area 51 is 480. What exactly do you mean by "my reputation score there is >7K"? Where do you see that?

Comment: I think you mean your network flair - perhaps this will explain: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/ - see the "combined network flair" section.

Answer (score 8):

If the site is closed, your reputation there no longer matters. The site is gone. Posts may be archived, but the site itself is no longer there.

If you fulfilled an Area 51 commitment on the site, then AFAIK your +50 rep on Area 51 should remain. You earned those points, and did your duty to try and keep the site alive. It would be unfair to take these from you.
Note that you only get these +50 after the private beta completes. If the site gets closed during public beta, you should get to keep those points. If the site does not survive private beta, then you never get those Area 51 points in the first place.

Some of the questions may get migrated to other Stack Exchange sites. If you have or open an account to this migration target, you will find that you have the appropriate amount of reputation points there.

Comment: Of course the reputation doesn't matter on any other side, only one might start 101 instead of 1 reputation if one is active elsewhere and 51/151 on Area 51

Comment: @Medi1Saif The association bonus should remain (the +100) should remain, as Oded pointed out.. in the rare case that the private beta was the first account where you got 200 points. It is possible that if Area 51 is the place where you got your first 200, that your Area 51 reputation will not result in an association bonus for the other sites. I'm not sure, but I recall a friend of mine having something like that. Area 51 runs on an old version of the SE engine, and doesn't always play nice with the normal SE sites.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the commitment-fulfillment code doesn't trigger until a site goes into public beta.

Comment: @Mark True. Updated the answer to make this clear.